# libtooling can't find stddef.h nor other headers

Tags: clang

I am writing a tool to parse C family source code projects basically following these two tutorials [1](http://kevinaboos.blogspot.com/2013/07/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling.html) [2](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) on clang 3.4 (trunk 192426) on ubuntu 12.04.

Based on [offical tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html), it says I could pass `compile_commands.json` by `-p`, however, if I only type `$ ./main -p [path of compile_commands.json]`, it will complain about missing positional arguments. It seems like I still need to pass all file names as arguments, which is not practical if the project is really huge. I prefer it could simply parse all files specified in `compile_commands.json` without asking but can't find out how to turn that on.

Since I can't find a tutorial for [CommonOptionsParser](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1CommonOptionsParser.html) to do any customize thing, I use [CompilationDatabase](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1CompilationDatabase.html) class instead. There is a dummy visitor returning `true` for `VisitStmt`, `VisitDecl` and `VisitType` so I'll skip that. The `main` function is pretty simple:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    string errorMsg = "";
    CompilationDatabase *cd = CompilationDatabase::autoDetectFromDirectory (argv[1], errorMsg);
    ClangTool Tool(*cd, cd->getAllFiles());

    int result = Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<ExampleFrontendAction>());

    return result;
}
```

I choose [`opencv`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) to parse since using cmake gaurantee the correctness of `compile_commands.json`(right?). However, a lot of errors show up (attached in the end). LibTooling complain about it can't find `stdarg.h`, `stddef.h` nor `emmintrin.h`. It's a [FAQ](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html) for clang, but it says why that will happen, but didn't say how to solve that while using libtooling. Pass all arguments for `clang -###` for clang could solve that, but how to pass those arguments while using libtooling?

```
# include <stdarg.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/openexr/IlmImf/ImfCompressionAttribute.cpp.
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libjpeg/jmemansi.c:16:
/home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libjpeg/jinclude.h:35:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include <stddef.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libjpeg/jmemansi.c.
error: no suitable precompiled header file found in directory '/home/jcwu/repos/opencv/modules/legacy/precomp.hpp.gch'
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/modules/legacy/src/hmmobs.cpp.
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libwebp/enc/quant.c:17:
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libwebp/enc/../dsp/../enc/vp8enci.h:17:
/usr/include/string.h:34:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include <stddef.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/3rdparty/libwebp/enc/quant.c.
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/modules/imgproc/opencv_test_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/modules/imgproc/test/test_precomp.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/iostream:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/ostream:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/ios:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/iosfwd:42:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/bits/postypes.h:42:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/cwchar:46:
/usr/include/wchar.h:40:11: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
# include <stdarg.h>
```

==== Update ====

Read CommonOptionsParser.cpp source code. It uses FixedCompilationDatabase to guess CompilationDatabase by arguments after --, then pass arguments before -- for custom (only -p in CommonOptionParser) options. In my case compile_commands.json is required, so I could skip using CommonOptionsParser.

Therefore my problem reduce to how to pass those options from "clang -###" to LibTooling when I have a compile_commands.json? Should I invoke shell command for every file I want to parse?

==== Update ====

I think modify compile_commands.json might be easier. I'm not sure why the compile_commands.json generated by CMake won't include my system header files folder correctly, since the Makefile generate by that CMakeList.txt could compile correctly, how come the compile_commands.json miss a lot of things.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar issue using the python bindings.

`[<Diagnostic severity 4, location <SourceLocation file '/usr/include/stdio.h', line 33, column 11>, spelling "'stddef.h' file not found">]`

In the "Tips" section at

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html

they mention that the default include path is

```
$(dirname /path/to/tool)/../lib/clang/3.3/include
```

The idea here it seems, is that it is expected that your tool is executing from the bin directory that also contains the clang executable itself. Typically, this will be a system directory so going up one from that will have the lib directory which contains the `clang/3.4/includ`e directory. So I manually included `$(which clang)../lib/clang/3.4/include` to the parser. In python, this looks something like

```
translation_unit = index.parse("test.cc",["-I/home/archgoon/usr/local/lib/clang/3.4/include"])
```

This resulted in `translation_unit.diagnostics` being an empty list.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was getting the error having installed clang-tidy but not clang as well on Ubuntu.

Comment: Spot on! Makes you wonder why `clang` is not a `clang-tidy` dependency - the latter might _run_ without the former, but you can't really use it for anything without it...

Answer (score 1):

Someone replied me says compilation database should be self contained. First I need to make sure the compile_commands.json is generated with using clang and I could use clang to build opencv.

I set these environment variables

```
export CC=/home/jcwu/repos/llvm-release/Release/bin/clang 
export CXX=/home/jcwu/repos/llvm-release/Release/bin/clang++ 
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include:/home/jcwu/repos/llvm-release/Release/lib/clang/3.4/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/include  # these are from clang -v -c files.cpp 
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include:/home/jcwu/repos/llvm-release/Release/lib/clang/3.4/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/include
```

then regenerate compile_commands.json, it could find stddef.h but new issue comes up

```
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o 
In file included from /home/jcwu/repos/opencv/modules/ts/src/ts.cpp:116: 
/usr/include/setjmp.h:60:12: error: conflicting types for '__sigsetjmp' 
extern int __sigsetjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag __env[1], int __savemask) __THROWNL; 
           ^ 
/usr/include/pthread.h:727:12: note: previous declaration is here 
extern int __sigsetjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag *__env, int __savemask) __THROW; 
           ^ 
1 error generated. 
make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/all] Error 2 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't use clang to build opencv due to a type conflict or two system header files. 
Havne't figured out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problem, which panics stddef.h not found, when I invoke clang-tidy against a compile_commands.json. In my case, the reason is that, the `clang-tidy` was based on llvm version ***7***, and the `clang++` version was based on llvm version ***4.0***, after changing clang-tidy to the right version ,the problems vanished.

Comment: Thanks! I had same issue, was using clang-tidy6 with clang++-9. Upgrading to clang-tidy-9 fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the matching clang's version for your tools and the first argumnent of the compile command (and use the right path).

For example:

```
  std::vector<std::string> Args {"/home/theuser/.local/llvm-8.0.0/bin/clang-8", "-c", "a.cpp"};
  llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::FileManager> fileManager(new clang::FileManager(clang::FileSystemOptions()));
  clang::tooling::ToolInvocation invoker(Args, new BlankAction(), fileManager.get());
  invoker.run();
```

If you use clang 8.0's library to build this tool, it will succeed. If you use the other versions (clang 3.6, etc.), it may cause this error.