# What's the difference between Clang invoked by Bash and the ClangTool?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-ast-matchers

## The original question

I followed a tutorial and created a tool named `ast_extract` to analyze the source code of libpng:

```cpp
llvm::cl::OptionCategory ASTExtractCategory("ASTExtract tool options");
llvm::Expected<clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser> optionParser = clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, ASTExtractCategory);
clang::tooling::ClangTool tool(optionParser->getCompilations(), optionParser->getCompilations().getAllFiles());
```

However, the tool encounters an issue where it cannot locate the 'stddef.h' file, as indicated in the following error message:

```bash
1 error generated.
Error while processing /data/tfk/study/PUT/libpng/pngmem.c.
In file included from contrib/libtests/pngvalid.c:27:
/usr/include/signal.h:301:11: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
  301 | # include <stddef.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I can temporarily resolve this by adding an extra parameter, such as `ast_extract --extra-arg='-I/data/tfk/llvm/lib/clang/17/include'`. However, when using Bash, I can simply copy the command lines from `compile_commands.json` without encountering any issues:

```bash
clang -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pngmem.o pngmem.c
```

How can I modify the `ast_extract` tool to eliminate the need for the extra argument?

## Update

Thanks to scott! I've successfully implemented the mentioned first solution by incorporating the following rules into CMakeLists.txt

```
# Install the compiler header files that libtool cannot find (such as stddef.h)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
install(TARGETS ast_extract DESTINATION bin)
install(DIRECTORY ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR}/../lib/clang/${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}/include DESTINATION lib/clang/${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR})

message(STATUS "LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Despite my best efforts to minimize hard-coding, the path to stddef.h (`${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR}/../lib/clang/${LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR}/include`) appears somewhat cumbersome.

**I'm curious if there's a CMake variable that directly corresponds to the needed path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference, in a nutshell, is that the `clang` invoked by `bash` has its compiler headers (including `stddef.h`) nearby in the file system, while your LibTooling executable does not.

Parsing C++ requires more than just a program that can read C++ syntax.  It also requires certain header files that are logically part of the compiler rather than the C library; `stddef.h` is one of the former, while (say) `stdio.h` is one of the latter.  If you use LibTooling to create an executable that parses C++, it is incomplete without the compiler headers, like a video game executable missing its art assets.  (And like a video game could package its art into the executable, a LibTooling executable could have the compiler headers embedded into it, but the LibTooling API is not set up to do that easily, unfortunately.)

So how does a LibTooling program find its compiler headers?  There are several APIs that accept an `argv`-like array, including the one used in your code, [`clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser::create`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1CommonOptionsParser.html#a04f3f4e5b050206ebd403c609048f380).  These APIs arrange to look for the compiler headers relative to the `argv[0]` in that array, in, essentially, `$(argv[0])/../lib/clang/$(version)/include`.  Consequently, you need to ensure that directory exists and is populated with all of the required files.

**Solution**: The proper way to do that is for your tool to have an "install" step or similar that copies the Clang compiler headers along with the executable to a location from which the latter will run.  You need to copy every file in `lib/clang/$(version)/include`.

However, since that's somewhat annoying, what I typically do is have my `Makefile` pass a `-D` switch that gives the path to the Clang installation directory I'm using, and then in my C++ code, I simply replace the `argv[0]` that was passed in by the shell with `$(clang_install_dir)/bin/clang`, effectively lying to the Clang API to impersonate `clang` itself.  Then the API will find the same compiler headers that `clang` finds.  This of course means my tool only works when a compatible version of `clang` is installed in that location, so it's suitable for experimentation and one-off development but a tool shouldn't do that if it's going to be installed and used by others.  A complete example is in my [`print-clang-ast`](https://github.com/smcpeak/print-clang-ast) tool.

For reference, there are several other questions and discussions that pertain to this topic, although none have a question and sufficiently complete answer that make it suitable as a duplicate target:

- [libtooling can't find stddef.h nor other headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642590/libtooling-cant-find-stddef-h-nor-other-headers)
- [fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found when using clang-llvm ASTMatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829339/fatal-error-stddef-h-file-not-found-when-using-clang-llvm-astmatcher)
- [<stddef.h> not found when running a standalone clang tool on .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187749/stddef-h-not-found-when-running-a-standalone-clang-tool-on-cpp-file)
- [Stddef.h not found, size_t not defined using libclang](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/stddef-h-not-found-size-t-not-defined-using-libclang/64309/2)
- [IWYU could not find stddef.h on Ubuntu 18.04](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues/679)

Some of those provide different workarounds, including passing an additional `-I` argument, which works as you've noted, but is not a good solution in general.

Comment: Thank you, the problem that has been bothering me for a long time has finally been solved. By the way, I initially assumed that ${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS} would reference the required path, but based on the output, ${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS} and ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS} appear to be the same (`/data/tfk/llvm/include`). Do you know is there any CMake variable pointing to the required path?

Comment: @FankeTong Right, `CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS` points at the headers needed to compile Clang (or a LibTooling program), not the headers that need to be deployed with it.  I am not aware of a CMake variable that points at the latter, but that doesn't mean much because I don't know a lot about CMake in general.